# Answer to these review questions

Tags: java

I have a java test coming up and this java professor is trying to pick a fight with me because I said I know my stuff.

This specific question is what set off an exchange of loud swearing.

```
    1. Suppose that c1 and c2 are reference variables of type Clock. 
    What is the effect of each of the following statements?

    a. c1= new Clock();

    Answer
    a. It creates the object c1, and the instance variables hr, min,
    and sec are initialized to 0.
```

My answer was that it instanstiates the Clock object with the default or no-argument constructor. But, NO, his answer was that it sets all instance variables to 0.

My question is how would you answer that? How would I have known the variables are there? I asked my professor, he answered saying, "If I post the code it would have been 3 pages long." Couldn't he have put "int hr, min, sec; for the first line?!

Comment: I do agree with you... but i feel this is off-topic of stackoverflow...

Comment: I didn't know where else to post, it still is a programming question... what does that line of code do...

Comment: Without seeing the implementation of Clock how could you know what instance variables were set?

Comment: Your teacher should either show the code upfront or accept your answer.

Comment: Well, it is no secret, that the constructor initializes all fields with their default value, if there is no other value specified. You can't tell which fields this class may have, but this part of the object instantiation should be clear.

Comment: Did you also get to see the implementation of Clock? If not then for all you know it doesn't have any instance variables. You also don't necessarily know that Clock() is the default no args constructor. There may be an explicit no args constructor that is defined on Clock.

Comment: I agree with your answer but If your professor has a stackoverflow profile. I'd like to hear his side of story.

Comment: *"I have a java test coming up ... "* -  Advice: put your ego back in its box and study for the test.  *"This specific question is what set off an exchange of loud swearing."* - That sounds like an inappropriate response ... no matter who is technically right.

Comment: @StephenC, why? To become another programming robot? Memorizing correct answers is the easiest way which brings the least.

Comment: @AlexShesterov - Surely that isn't the only question he is going to get.  He should study for the rest of them ... and not waste his time with this pedantic debate.  And probably learn to moderate his behaviour.

Comment: @StephenC, well, _that's_ true :)

Comment: @AlexShesterov - Well **that** was the point I was trying to make :-)

Comment: @StephenC This is one of the review questions. How can I properly study for a test that, according to my professor, I can't answer correctly. Also, I didn't start the heated argument first. I asked calmly what variables it's referring to, he kept getting agitated and increased the volume of his voice, so I increased mine.

Comment: "*How can I properly study for a test that, according to my professor, I can't answer correctly.*" - Easy.  Ignore that question.  Anyway, this is NOT an appropriate place to deal with conflict with your lecturer.  Either just let it pass ... or take it up with your University.  Frankly, I would advise the former.  This is what most people would call "a storm in a teacup".

Comment: Also - to everyone else.  Remember that we are only hearing one side of this.  And ... frankly ... I wish we weren't hearing even one side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement

```
c1 = new Clock();
```

Creates a new instance of the class Clock, using its no args constructor, and assigns it to the local variable c1. Without knowing the implementation of Clock or the implementation of its no args constructor there is no way know knowing what the internal state of the instance c1 is upon construction. Member variables may have been set by the constructor or by static initialization. Your guess is as good as mine.

I think it worth pointing out that without seeing the implementation of Clock you do not know if Clock() is the default no args constructor or a defined constructor that takes no args.

Comment: Upped because separation between no args constructor and default constructor.

Comment: "I think it worth pointing out that without seeing the implementation of Clock you do not know if Clock() is the default no args constructor or a defined constructor that takes no args."                                                            That's what I told my professor, but he answered with, "I can't show the code without having to print 3 pages out"

Answer (score 0):

Some people like to show how "smart" and educated they are. Maybe (just maybe) that's your professor's case.

---

Looking at the statement `c1= new Clock();`, the only thing one can say is that a new instance of class `Clock` is created, using its no-arguments constructor, and the reference to the created instance is assigned to a variable named `c1`, which must have been declared previously (the variable may or may not have already been initialized). Instantiation includes initializing class fields, if default values are defined, e.g. `private int myField = 4711;`, otherwise default values for primitives are used (`int`s default to `0`s).

Without seeing class implementation, you just *can't* know which fields are initialized and how.

A `Clock` can store its state in different ways — that's what *encapsulation* is about. For example, it may store *timestamp* — number of milliseconds since the epoch. Or since the beginning of the day. It may also store hours+minutes+seconds, of course, but you can't know, and you should *not* guess anything.

---

There's also [class `Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) in Java since 1.8. Maybe your professor meant this class — I can't tell as I don't know the context.